# Create csv out of array of objects with nested array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object, nested

So I'm trying to take these two pieces of data

```
const headers = [
      { label: 'Item/Passage', key: 'objectType' },
      { label: 'Constraint Type', key: 'constraintType' },
      { label: 'Constraint Name', key: 'description' },
      { label: 'Lower', key: 'lowerBound' },
      { label: 'Upper', key: 'upperBound' },
      { label: 'Target Attribute', key: 'attributeName' },
      { label: 'Theta', key: 'referenceValue' },
      { label: 'Form/Passage', key: 'scope' },
      { label: 'Filter', key: 'filters' },
      { label: 'Filter values', key: 'filterValues' },
      { label: 'Min', key: 'min' },
      { label: 'Max', key: 'max' },
    ];
```

```
const array = [
  {
    "objectType": "Item",
    "constraintType": "Include",
    "description": "constraint1",
    "lowerBound": "1",
    "filters": [
      {
        "attributeName": "Item Identifier",
        "values": "I105_15201|I105_15202",
        "valueLowerBound": null,
        "valueUpperBound": null
      },
      {
        "attributeName": "Passage Item Order",
        "values": "5|1|3|4|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|None",
        "valueLowerBound": null,
        "valueUpperBound": null
      }
    ],
    "upperBound": "4",
    "attributeName": null,
    "referenceValue": "",
    "scope": null
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Passage",
    "constraintType": "Include",
    "description": "constraint2",
    "lowerBound": "1",
    "filters": [
      {
        "attributeName": "Passage Identifier",
        "values": "pid_1-1|pid_10-1|pid_2-1|pid_4-1|pid_5-1|pid_7-1|pid_8-1|pid_9-1",
        "valueLowerBound": null,
        "valueUpperBound": null
      },
      {
        "attributeName": "Word Count",
        "values": "",
        "valueLowerBound": 3,
        "valueUpperBound": 234
      }
    ],
    "upperBound": "4",
    "attributeName": null,
    "referenceValue": "",
    "scope": null
  },
  {
    "objectType": "Item",
    "constraintType": "Include",
    "description": "constraint3",
    "filters": [],
    "lowerBound": "1",
    "upperBound": "4",
    "attributeName": null,
    "referenceValue": "",
    "scope": null
  }
]
```

And produce a csv file that looks like this,

[image]

Basically, I take the label values from the header array, create the header, then each constraint is put on its own row. If a constraint has filters, another row is created and the values are placed within the last four columns. For example, constraint1 and 2 have two filters, constraint 3 has none.

I've been able to accomplish already with the following code, but feel it's not a terribly stable implementation. Looking for any suggestions on how to implement this. Thanks!

Here is the copy of the string I've been able to create

```
toCsv -> csv Item/Passage,Constraint Type,Constraint Name,Lower,Upper,Target Attribute,Theta,Form/Passage,Filter,Filter values,Min,Max
Item,Include,constraint1,1,4,,,
,,,,,,,,Item Identifier,I105_15201|I105_15202,,
,,,,,,,,Passage Item Order,5|1|3|4|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|None,,
Passage,Include,constraint2,1,4,,,
,,,,,,,,Passage Identifier,pid_1-1|pid_10-1|pid_2-1|pid_4-1|pid_5-1|pid_7-1|pid_8-1|pid_9-1,,
,,,,,,,,Word Count,,3,234
Item,Include,constraint3,1,4,,,
```

```
export const toCsv = (array, headers) => {
  const getValuesFromObject = (obj) => {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
      return [];
    }

    const headerKeys = Object.keys(headers);
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    const values = [];
    const filterValues = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[keys[i]])) {
        obj[keys[i]].map((filterObj) => {
          filterValues.push(',,,,,,,,' + Object.values(filterObj)); // this part bothers me the most. I use it to create empty cells for the filter rows.
        });
      } else {
        values.push(obj[keys[i]]);
      }
    }
    return [].concat([values]).concat(filterValues).join('\n');
  };

  const csvHeaders = headers.map((obj) => obj.label).join(',');
  const body = array.map(getValuesFromObject);
  let csv = [].concat([csvHeaders]).concat(body).join('\n');
  return csv;
};
```

Comment: do you have an example of the wanted result (in text form) of the above data?

Comment: @NinaScholz I've just added a copy of the csv string I have been able to create. Does that help?

Comment: it look like, you have two type of rows and you address in the headers only one/none type. maybe it would be better to have a separation between  items and their filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a single loop for the objects, their filters and iterate the keys.

```js
const
    toCsv = (array, headers) => {
        const getValuesFromObject = o => !o || typeof o !== 'object'
            ? []
            : [
                headers.map(({ key }) => key !== 'filters' && o[key] || '').join(),
                ...o.filters.map(q => headers.map(({ key }) => q[key] || '').join())
            ];

        return [
            headers.map((obj) => obj.label).join(','),
            ...array.flatMap(getValuesFromObject)
        ].join('\n');
    },
    headers = [{ label: 'Item/Passage', key: 'objectType' }, { label: 'Constraint Type', key: 'constraintType' }, { label: 'Constraint Name', key: 'description' }, { label: 'Lower', key: 'lowerBound' }, { label: 'Upper', key: 'upperBound' }, { label: 'Target Attribute', key: 'attributeName' }, { label: 'Theta', key: 'referenceValue' }, { label: 'Form/Passage', key: 'scope' }, { label: 'Filter', key: 'filters' }, { label: 'Filter values', key: 'values' }, { label: 'Min', key: 'valueLowerBound' }, { label: 'Max', key: 'valueUpperBound' }],
    array = [{ objectType: "Item", constraintType: "Include", description: "constraint1", lowerBound: "1", filters: [{ attributeName: "Item Identifier", values: "I105_15201|I105_15202", valueLowerBound: null, valueUpperBound: null }, { attributeName: "Passage Item Order", values: "5|1|3|4|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|None", valueLowerBound: null, valueUpperBound: null }], upperBound: "4", attributeName: null, referenceValue: "", scope: null }, { objectType: "Passage", constraintType: "Include", description: "constraint2", lowerBound: "1", filters: [{ attributeName: "Passage Identifier", values: "pid_1-1|pid_10-1|pid_2-1|pid_4-1|pid_5-1|pid_7-1|pid_8-1|pid_9-1", valueLowerBound: null, valueUpperBound: null }, { attributeName: "Word Count", values: "", valueLowerBound: 3, valueUpperBound: 234 }], upperBound: "4", attributeName: null, referenceValue: "", scope: null }, { objectType: "Item", constraintType: "Include", description: "constraint3", filters: [], lowerBound: "1", upperBound: "4", attributeName: null, referenceValue: "", scope: null }],
    result = toCsv(array, headers);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, but the above only shows five commas before each filter instead of seven to move the filter name into the correct Filter column. For example, ,,,,Item Identifier,,,,. The output would need to be, ,,,,,,,Item Identifier,I105_15201|... I'm still working through you logic so I don't have a solution yet. Just noting the output I'm seeing.

Comment: `attributeName` is on index 5, `filters` on index 8. the values are taken from the given key  of headers and inseted at the index position. if you like to have a certain value at a different index, you need to have a corresponding key at this position.